# Error while using PDF Kit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, pdfkit

I am trying to use PDFKit using rails 3, I followed the railscast tutorial and found that I get the following error:

> > : undefined method `wrap_parameters' for ActionController::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're accidentally loading Rails 3.0.x on a Rails 3.1 application?

It won't work if you generate a Rails 3.1 application, which adds `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`, and then try to boot it with Rails 3.0.x.

If you want Rails 3.1:
Are you running with bundler, e.g. `bundle exec unicorn_rails` or `bundle exec rake`?

If you want Rails 3.0.x:
Regenerate the application by running `rails new appname` to see what needs to change.