# Downgradind from rails 3.1 to 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For reasons of compatibility with another project i'd like to downgrade rails 3.1 to 3.0.9 but i'm scared to lose some functionality! At the same time i would change the adapter of migration.yml from sqlite3 to mysql.

Right now is the standard one:

```
development:
 adapter: sqlite3
 database: db/development.sqlite3
```

I would change it in something like:

```
development:
 adapter: mysql
 encoding: utf8
 database: myapp_dev
 host: localhost
 username: username
 password: pass
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**

I started working to a project with rails 3.1.0, then i downloaded and developed another project made using rails 3.0.9. Now when i came back to the first project, loading home page, i get back

```
undefined method `clear_active_connections!' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class
```

and if i type something like:

```
rake db:migrate
```

application claims one gem located in Gemefile.lock of the other application!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that only changing the database.yml for mysql it works, but I do not know about the update, keep a backup and make tests before you make it through.

Comment: Thank you very much, but according to this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677352/error-while-using-pdf-kit?answertab=active#tab-top) the only way is creating a new project!